# My Maven Vaadin Project (created with IntelliJ Idea 13) cannot see an interface class which belongs to an already declared maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, vaadin

I have created a maven vaadin project using IntelliJ Idea 13 using vaadin-archetype-application:7.1.9

In this project I have declared the following pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MavenVaadinClientSideApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenVaadinClientSideApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Vaadin Web Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <vaadin.version>7.1.9</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>${vaadin.version}</vaadin.plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
          Needed when using the widgetset optimizer (custom ConnectorBundleLoaderFactory).

          For widgetset compilation, vaadin-client-compiler is automatically added on the
          compilation classpath by vaadin-maven-plugin so normally there is no need for an
          explicit dependency.
        -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
            <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- As we are doing "inplace" GWT compilation, ensure the widgetset -->
            <!-- directory is cleaned properly -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <!-- <runTarget>mobilemail</runTarget> -->
                    <!-- We are doing "inplace" but into subdir VAADIN/widgetsets. This 
                        way compatible with Vaadin eclipse plugin. -->
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                    </webappDirectory>
                    <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets
                    </hostedWebapp>
                    <noServer>true</noServer>
                    <!-- Remove draftCompile when project is ready -->
                    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                    <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                    <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- if you don't specify any modules, the plugin will find them -->
                            <!-- <modules> <module>com.vaadin.demo.mobilemail.gwt.ColorPickerWidgetSet</module> 
                                </modules> -->
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            vaadin-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [7.1.9,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>resources</goal>
                                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

As you can see vaadin-client is already declared.
The problem is that when I am trying to use com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint interface that belongs to this package IntelliJ Idea 13 Ultimate cannot import it (see the image below)
[image: Error image]

Any ideas?

Comment: May be you forgot to write an import...?

Comment: I have tried to import the interface manually but it is not working. If intellij idea could 'see' the interface class it could have auto imported it anyway.

Comment: Finally the manual method worked after I disable the 'optimize imports on the fly' setting!

Comment: please answer your own question and mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

The manual method worked along with a disable of 'optimise imports on the fly' setting.